# Ho to send a "BULK in" message with pyusb with python

Tags: python, pyusb

I would like to recover data from my sound level meter Velleman Dem202

For that I have decided to use python pyusb to access from my Host to the Device

To understand the protocol exchange used, I have scanned the message exchanges with wireshark usb traffic capture.

For example, based on

[image]

I could identify the parameter to use for ctrl_transfer

```
    import usb.core

    def connect():
        dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x10C4, idProduct=0xEA60)
        assert dev is not None
        print(dev)
        return dev

    def readSPL(dev):
        ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0xC0, 16, 0, 0, 200) # wvalue (3rd arg) is ignored
        return(ret) 

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        # connect Device over USB
        dev = connect()

        while True:
            ret = readSPL(dev)
            print(ret)
            time.sleep(1)
```

My question is following:

How to read the "BULK in" message with pyusb

This message seems to read the "decibel info data" from my DEVICE

[image]

How to adapt the code to get the answer of frame 3039 below

[image]

Thanks